# Electrical layout for room addition

Tags: electrical

I have a contractor building the shell of a room addition, while I will be completing the electrical work.  I need to supply a layout with outlets, lights, fans, and switches.  The upper left area will be a mudroom with locker/bench storage.

I know that I need an outlet near the sink but I am unclear on if outlets need to be placed in the long hallway or the shower area.  Do I need outlets in these areas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> In dwelling units, hallways of 3.0 m (10 ft) or more in length shall
> have at least one receptacle outlet. As used in this subsection, the
> hallway length shall be considered the length along the centerline of
> the hallway without passing through a doorway.
>
> At least one receptacle outlet shall be installed in bathrooms within
> 900 mm (3 ft) of the outside edge of each basin. The receptacle outlet
> shall be located on a wall or partition that is adjacent to the basin
> or basin countertop, located on the countertop, or installed on the
> side or face of the basin cabinet. In no case shall the receptacle be
> located more than 300 mm (12 in.) below the top of the basin or basin
> countertop. Receptacle outlet assemblies listed for use in countertops
> shall be permitted to be installed in the countertop.

The above is 2020, Minnesota.  https://up.codes/viewer/minnesota/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.52

The mudroom will have the 6 ft max to a plug requirement.

If you put an outlet within 6 ft of the shower it must be GFCI.

I've never lived in a house where I thought there were enough outlets.

Comment: Last sentence: +100! I'm currently adding a _small_ bathroom & closet. There will be 2 outlets on every wall in the closet. There will be outlets for all the "needed" things in the bathroom, plus about 4 extra "just in case".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no requirement that outlets be made available in the hallway. Do you think you will want them there?

I'm not sure what you mean by "the shower area".

Outlet by the sink is common these days, for hair driers and electric toothbrushes and so on. So you probably do want one there. But that isn't a requirement either.

Figure out how the occupants are going to use the building. Put outlets where the occupants will want outlets to be.

Comment: I think Tiger Guy's answer shows that there is need for outlets in a hallway. (Or, at least, _some_ hallways)

Comment: I suspect this varies by country. Measurements in the drawing in the question pretty much guarantee US or Canada, so NEC applies. NEC, as noted in the other answer, requires bathroom and hallway receptacles. There are variants by state and version of NEC, but the basic requirements are pretty consistent.

Comment: OK; didn't know that hallway receptacles were now required by NEC. I've never lived in a house which had them. I can see why they'd be _useful_, and maybe arguments for why they'd be _desirable_ (fewer extension cords, less risk of pinching a cord in a door), but required greatly surprises me. Learn something every day....